# Calling a super toString() method but using current class' variables

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, tostring

say we have 2 classes:

```
public class A {

    private String name = "A";

    public String toString()
    {
        return (name + "some random text");
    }
}

public class B extends A{

    private String name = "B";
    public String toString()
    {
        return (super.toString());
    }
}
```

When I tried to print the `B.toString()` in my driver class, it will still print the name from class A instead of the name from class B. How can I change it so it will use the variable name from class B instead?

Comment: 1. Remove `private String name = "B";` 2. Add a constructor on class A to set name. 3. Add a constructor in class B which calls the super constructor with "B" passed as the value for name..... reason: calling `super.toString()` will use the name variable in class A which is defined as "A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through the use of constructors -

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a = new A("A String");
     B b = new B("B String");
     System.out.println(a.toString()); // A String some random text
     System.out.println(b.toString()); // B String some random text
   }
}

class A {
  protected String name;

  A(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name + " some random text";
  }
}

class B extends A {

  B(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return (super.toString());
  }

}
```

Because `B` inherits from `A`, the `name` field is setup correctly when you pass a string to the constructor for `B`.

Comment: The thing is, I already have a constructor that takes in other parameters without the name, and the variable name in my classes A and B are already predetermined, I don't know if I'm being clear enough..